# Django deploy on App Engine raise error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed:

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

i am trying to deploy my django web app on Google Cloud App Engine, but are running to a connection error. This is after I have done all the configuration like main.py, entry point, app.yaml.

After doing some digging, they all point to my postgresql database blocking my connections somehow, but i checked and my database is up and running on sql cloud.

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[the error image][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDIfY.png

Here is my **app.yaml** file:

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python38

handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: django_blog.wsgi.application

env_variables:
    APPENGINE_URL: https://engineblog.wn.r.appspot.com

#entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT django_project.wsgi:main

inbound_services:
- warmup

# Only pure Python libraries can be vendored
# Python libraries that use C extensions can
# only be included if they are part of the App Engine SDK 
# Using Third Party Libraries: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27
# libraries:
# - name: MySQLdb
#   version: 1.2.5
# [END django_app].
```

Here is my **home.html** which is the file that django show for the error

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in post_list %}
<div class="post-entry">
    <h2>
        <a href="">{{ post.title }}</a>
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
    </h2>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

and my **setting.py** file:

```
"""
Django settings for django_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "this is secret"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*", "https://engineblog.wn.r.appspot.com"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "blog.apps.BlogConfig",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "django_project.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "django_project.wsgi.application"

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

if os.getenv("TRAMPOLINE_CI", None):
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
        }
    }
WSGI_APPLICATION = "django_project.wsgi.application"

import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

# [START db_setup]
if os.getenv("SERVER_SOFTWARE", "").startswith("Google App Engine"):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
            "HOST": "/cloudsql/connectionstring",
            "NAME": "dbname",
            "USER": "dbuser",
            "PASSWORD": "dbpassword",
        }
    }

else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
            "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
            "PORT": "5432",
            "NAME": "dbname",
            "USER": "dbuser",
            "PASSWORD": "db_password",
        }
    }

# [END db_setup]
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = "static"

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

I am at my witt end here, so I would appreciate the help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDIfY.png

Comment: So, I see in your settings file, you have host set to "/cloudsql/connectionstring". connectionstring isn't expanded anywhere, so I'm guessing you just didn't update it? You need to set that connection string to the right unix socket connection string for the db engine you're connecting to. Check the documentation for the right format. If that's it I'll create an answer for you to accept.

Comment: the "connectionstring" is just a placeholder because the actual code contains instance-id, region, and the such so I did not want to leak it.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. :) Glad you found the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#detecting_application_runtime_environment), to check if you're running in Production or not, you should be doing

```
if os.getenv('GAE_ENV', '').startswith('standard'):
  # Production in the standard environment
else:
  # Local execution.
```

If you print the dict for os.getenv, you will see a value of `gunicorn/20.1.0.` for "SERVER_SOFTWARE"